# Reshape dataframe from horizontal to vertical in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to convert an excel file as follows from horizontal to vertical:

[image]

Use `pd.read_clipboard` I get:

```
                         2017   2018   2019
city price ratio price  ratio  price  ratio
bj   10    0.1   13       0.1     23    0.1
sh   15    0.2   12       0.2     15    0.5
gz   12    0.15  14      0.15     12    0.1
sz   11    0.25  13      0.25     11    0.5
```

I modified `year` header to make it look better:

```
         2017        2018          2019
city price ratio price  ratio  price  ratio
bj   10    0.1   13       0.1     23    0.1
sh   15    0.2   12       0.2     15    0.5
gz   12    0.15  14      0.15     12    0.1
sz   11    0.25  13      0.25     11    0.5
```

How can I convert it to the expected output like this? Thanks.

```
   city  year  price  ratio
0    bj  2017     10   0.10
1    bj  2018     13   0.10
2    bj  2019     23   0.10
3    sh  2017     15   0.20
4    sh  2018     12   0.20
5    sh  2019     15   0.50
6    gz  2017     12   0.15
7    gz  2018     14   0.15
8    gz  2019     12   0.10
9    sz  2017     11   0.25
10   sz  2018     13   0.25
11   sz  2019     11   0.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is `MultiIndex in columns` you can use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html),[`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('2017', 'price'),
            ('2018', 'ratio'),
            ('2019', 'price'),
            ('2017', 'ratio'),
            ('2018', 'price'),
            ('2019', 'ratio')],
           )

df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('city','year')).reset_index()
print (df)
   city  year  price  ratio
0    bj  2017     10   0.10
1    bj  2018     23   0.10
2    bj  2019     13   0.10
3    sh  2017     15   0.20
4    sh  2018     15   0.20
5    sh  2019     12   0.50
6    gz  2017     12   0.15
7    gz  2018     12   0.15
8    gz  2019     14   0.10
9    sz  2017     11   0.25
10   sz  2018     11   0.25
11   sz  2019     13   0.50
```

Comment: I use `clipboard`, only get `Index(['2017', '2018', '2019'], dtype='object')` as `df.columns`.

Comment: @ahbon - hmmm, in real data is possible use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1])` ? But then header has to be like `2017;2018;2019;2017;2018;2019` in first row and `price;ratio;price;ratio;price;ratio` in second (`;` is separator, so there should be `,`)

Comment: I use `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', index_col=[0], header=[0,1])`, then apply your code it works. Thanks.